# What am I supposed to do as a newbie if I want more info on a question?

Tags: discussion, new-users

So I am new here, and I am quite limited in what I can do in any of the forums. I completely understand why, but it is quite frustrating. If I see a question and want to ask a related question, [I cannot comment anywhere, as I don't have 50 reputation points] either I can post an answer that doesn't follow the guidelines, or I can not answer the question. If I post an answer that doesn't follow the guidelines... I don't know what could happen, but I don't like breaking rules anyways. If I don't answer the question, I don't get any closer to being able to get out of this newbie loop :(

How can I get more information, or just suggest something to the poster?

Comment: As one of your account is on [so] please read [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: What a great question to pinpoint how it is like to be a newbie. I just voted it up, and "suggested an edit" to it (trying to not change the msg included in the original question, fingers crossed it gets approved ...). At this very moment I "do not dare" (honestly! Go figure!) to add an extra link to some other question. I even hesitate to add here "why" I would want to add that extra link. Where are the experienced "mentors" on SE, willing to back me up and support me if I need help after adding that link here? Is somebody like 'Free Radical' around ... and willing to back me up ?

Comment: I realise that with "this" extra comment I'm putting my reputation at risk, but to be honest I do not care about possibly being downvoted from 100 to 0 ... To those who "have the privilege" to see my approved edits, please checkout my approved edit from a few minutes ago. If you agree with my constructive-attempt, please support it somehow ...

Comment: Please note my PS linking to this question in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251333/what-are-the-recommended-activities-for-a-new-user-such-as-for-asking-for-more I started that new question after my prior suggested edit to this question got rejected, something that was suggested to me by "James", an experienced SE user. And in the meantime I voted up this issue here (of course) ...